# autohotkey copy link text on click to clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to copy link text to the clipboard with autohotkey.  In my situation I would like to capture the link text using Control-LeftClick,  I then manipulate the text and construct a new link and navigate.  Currently I am doing:

```
browser="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Send, ^c 
Sleep 200
Run, %browser%  mySite.com/?s=%Clipboard%& ...
Return
```

However rather than using Send, ^c to copy the text when I select it, it would be much nicer if I could just get the text by using control-LeftClick on the link, selecting the link text without accidentally clicking it can be clumsy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

Install this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-link-address/kdejdkdjdoabfihpcjmgjebcpfbhepmh?hl=en   
**Second:**

**a.** If you want to copy to the clipboard link adress that is under your mouse cursor and after open that link to another window use this code:

```
^LButton::

    Send, ^c
    Send, {Ctrl Down}
    Click
    Send, {Ctrl Up}

return
```

**b.** If you want to copy to the clipboard link adress that is under your mouse cursor but dont open that link to another window use this code:

```
^LButton::

    Send, ^c

return
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, but very helpful.  I am looking to get the link TEXT, not the link url.  However, as it turns out in my case your solution is sufficient since the text is included in the link for my case so I can parse it out.  Based on your idea of using a chrome extension I found this link in the superuser forum  http://superuser.com/questions/173200/how-to-select-hyperlink-text-in-google-chrome which discusses extensions for selecting text.